# how to count number of digit in a vector? (in R)

Tags: r, vector, count, frequency, digits

Given a vector

```r
num <- c(1, 2, 4, 13, 25)
```

I want to count how many times each digit appears; in this case the result would be

| digit | times |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |

Answer (score 4):

You may try

```
table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(num), "")))

1 2 3 4 5 
2 2 1 1 1
```